# Computed property generates "Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword" error

Tags: ios, swift

Code below. Why does the "Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword" error occur? Isn't this the "Swift" way of providing getters and setters to properties?

```
class TestClass : UICollectionViewCell {
        var _selected = false

        var selected : Bool {
        get {
            return _selected
        }

        set {
            _selected = newValue
            selectedView.hidden = !_selected
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "Swift way" is to explicitly mark overriden methods and properties with the `override` keyword ;)

Answer (score 4):

First,don't use  `_selected` in Swift.It's Objective-C style.
Second, and `override` keyword before `var selected : Bool` because its super has declared a property with the same name.

**Update:**
This is a store value,you don't need to do anything to get its value because swift will store it automaticlly.

```
   override var selected : Bool {
    get {
      return super.selected
    }
    set {
        selectedView.hidden = !newValue
    }
    }
```

Or use didSet:

```
   override var selected : Bool {
    didSet {
        selectedView.hidden = !selected
    }
    }
```

Use store value to keep a persistence value.Use computing(which has a getter) to get real-time value.

Comment: If not _selected, what do you recommend?

Comment: @Crashalot In swift,use set,didSet,willSet,get and oldValue,newValue to handle a property. You can have a look at swift programming in iBook.

Comment: And also,you should differ computing and store value.

Comment: The problem with `set,didSet,willSet,get` is it breaks up the variable definitions, and I prefer them grouped together where each declaration is on one line for easier browsing. Know any way to use `set,didSet,willSet,get` while allowing for variables to be defined in a block (one line at a time)?

Comment: @Crashalot Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the reason for your error is that `UITableViewCell` already defines a property called `selected`.

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the answer by a few seconds! Upvoted, though.